# C# Socket Connections using VLANs

Tags: c#, tcp, vlan

Using C#, I am trying to establish a tcp connection, then send tcp packets to a remote device

```
Socket sock = new Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress destAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.30.5.222");
sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 14500));
sock.Connect(destAddress, 14500);
```

What happens is that my program sends an ARP request, but the remote device discards it.

Root cause that the remote device is accepting only vLan Tagged frames with a specific vLan Id. However, my C# code sends ethernet frames with out vlan tagging.

Is there any way to send vLan tagged frames?
I read about pcapdotnet. But as far as I understand it only send single packets.
and this means that I will need to do the following manually in the code to establish connection:

- send arp
- receive arp
- send syn
- receive syn ack
- send ack

same hassle in each sending, fragmentation, ...etc

**Is there a way to configure my communication to be vLan tagged, without writing packet by packet? (preferred in C#)**